# how to incorporate visual tree xml editor swing component?

Tags: java, xml, swing, editor, jtree

So far I have used dom4j's DefaultTreeModel to create a Jtree out of the xml file it reads.

The problem is that the Jtree doesn't refresh everytime the xml is changed, or a node is added or removed.

So far, it appears there is much plumbing code involved because there doesn't seem to be implementation of OnXmlChanged().

What other alternatives do I have of incorporating a visual tree xml swing component that also supports event firing upon change in the underlying xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can always fire these events your self when you know that something has changed, From DefaultTreeModel, use:

```
protected  void fireTreeNodesChanged(Object source, Object[] path, int[] childIndices, Object[] children) 

protected  void fireTreeNodesInserted(Object source, Object[] path, int[] childIndices, Object[] children) 

protected  void fireTreeNodesRemoved(Object source, Object[] path, int[] childIndices, Object[] children) 

protected  void fireTreeStructureChanged(Object source, Object[] path, int[] childIndices, Object[] children)
```

Comment: +1 See also [this alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664041/java-treetable-problem/5664525#5664525).

Comment: sure, it's possible - just ton's of work and not exactly reliable: the document might change under the feet of the both the model and any "agent" related to it. Couldn't find any obvious (low-workload) solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579580/expand-jtree-at-last-modified-area